# Can singleton class be static?

Tags: c#, class, static, singleton

Can singleton class be static?

Comment: day of singletones. forth question today about them :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No. A singleton class is meant to be instantiated, because the term itself refers to an instance; if you make it a static class, you can't create a singleton object out of it.

Comment: +1: A Singleton class may have a static method, through which you get the instance of the singleton object.

Answer (score 7):

(Cat, meet pigeons.)

Yes, but only in practice, not in theory.

A singleton is a class that can only be instantiated once. A static class cannot be instantiated, so it cannot be called a singleton.

However, since we're talking about C#, static classes have constructors, so it is in effect being instantiated, and there can only ever be one instance so that to me looks a lot like a singleton.

Comment: This really is the best answer, as its the only one that points out in C# you can in fact initialize a static class with a static ctor.  By strict definition its not a singleton, but by all practical applications you can consider it one.

Answer (score 6):

No. Singleton referes to single instance of the class. Static class does not have instances.

Answer (score 4):

A singleton is by definition an instance, so no.

But, you could have a static class where the methods access a private static variable. But that is just pushing the singleton a level deeper.

Answer (score 0):

No singleton cannot be static