# Why do static methods need to be wrapped into a class?

Tags: c#, static-methods

Sorry for the unlearned nature of this question. If there's a simple answer, just a link to an explanation will make me more than happy.

After 6 months programming I find static classes to be somewhat useful for storing routines that apply to many different classes. Here's a simplified example of how I use static classes, it's a class for parsing text into various things

```
public static class TextProcessor 
{
    public static string[] GetWords(string sentence)
    {
        return sentence.Split(' '); 
    }

    public static int CountLetters(string sentence)
    {
        return sentence.Length; 
    }

    public static int CountWords(string sentence)
    {
        return GetWords(sentence).Length; 
    }
}
```

And I use this in obvious ways like

```
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string mysentence = "hello there stackoverflow.";
        Console.WriteLine("mysentence has {0} words in it, fascinating huh??", TextProcessor.CountWords(mysentence)); 

        Console.ReadLine(); 
    }
}
```

My question is: Why is it necessary to wrap these static methods in a static class? 
It seems to serve no purpose. Is there a way I can have these methods on their own not wrapped in a class? I know encapsulation is beneficial but I don't see the use for static methods wrapped in static class. Is there something I am missing stylistically or otherwise? Am I completely barking up a silly tree? Am I thinking too much?

Comment: Great question, but I suspect it's just a boring "because Java did it."

Comment: It ultimately boils down to how the language was designed. All methods have to be in a class. Why? Probably for the sake of consistency.

Comment: check this [post][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7933540/c-sharp-static-class-why-use

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C#, any method has to be declared inside a class. That's just how the language is specified.

A static class is actually more [akin to a module](http://codecrafter.blogspot.com/2009/09/c-static-classes-are-not-real-classes.html) than a class, so I too think you should be able to either:

- define a function outside a class or;
- import a module the same way you import a namespace (with `using`)

VB.NET, F# and Nemerle actually allow you to declare modules and import them; what allows you to use their methods unqualified.

This is valid Nemerle:

```
using System.Console; // import static methods in the Console class
class Hello {
  static Main() : void {
    WriteLine("Hello, world!"); // unqualified access!
  }
}
```

Also, take a look at [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx), they might allow you to "solve" this in a different way. The methods in your `TextProcessor` are *begging* to be `string` extension methods.

Comment: Great, Nemerle looks interesting. Modules would be fantastic in c#.

Answer (score 2):

[This post by eric lippert](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/22/why-doesn-t-c-implement-top-level-methods.aspx) gives a pretty detailed explanation. I'm not sure if this guy "eric" knows what he's talking about or not though ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It would be somewhat awkward to have methods just dangling around in a random namespace.

I suspect the answer is to provide "scope".  Just because a method is static, doesn't mean it doesn't have a scope.  It can still access other static private methods or member variables - and the class provides a "home" for these things to live in.

Static classes can also have static constructors that get called the first time a static method is used, so this provides the ability to set stuff up as needed.

It's more of an organizational design than anything to due with technical limitations.

Comment: "It would be somewhat awkward to have methods just dangling around in a random namespace." - *Most* languages let you do that.

Comment: Most object oriented languages?

Comment: I see I see. So in a "hybrid" language like c++ you can have access to functions outside a class but in a rigid OO language like C# you have to encapsulate everything inside a class? .. makes sense. Makes for a lot more boilerplate code than is necessary I think.

Comment: Yea I think languages like C++ has to be "backwards compatible" with non-object-oriented C, so they kinda have to support it.  VB.NET has to be backwards compatible with BASIC (well, sorta)..  I think having classes as a root container for all code is pretty much a standard object-oriented way of thinking.  Though I'm sure now people will chime in with "what about language _____" :)

Answer (score -3):

A static method is a method called in a single instance of a class that is created at run-time.