# import a static method

Tags: c#, static-import

How can I import a static method from another c# source file and use it without "dots"?

like:

foo.cs

```
namespace foo
{
    public static class bar
    {
        public static void foobar()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```
using foo.bar.foobar; // <= can't!

namespace Program
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
             foobar();
        }
    }
}
```

I can't just `foobar();`, but if I write `using foo;` on the top and call `foobar()` as `foo.bar.foobar()` it works, despite being much verbose. Any workarounds to this?

Comment: If you write `using foo;` then `bar.foobar()` is all you need to invoke it. With a static method, you're always going to have at least one dot.

Comment: is writing bar.foobar() so verbose?

Comment: switch to VB.Net? "Module" in VB does the "trick" - kind of tribute to VB.classic users I guess.

Comment: Java supports static method imports. Just saying... :)

Comment: You might wanna change the accepted answer - this question has a big enough view count to occasionally be updated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> **This is the accepted answer, but note that as the answer below states, this is now possible in C# 6**

You can't

static methods needs to be in a class by design..

[Why do static methods need to be wrapped into a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8131546/why-do-static-methods-need-to-be-wrapped-into-a-class)

Answer (score 47):

**With C# 6.0 you can.**

C# 6.0 [allows static import (See using Static Member)](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Language%20Feature%20Status&referringTitle=Documentation)

You will be able to do:

```
using static foo.bar;
```

and then in your `Main` method you can do:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    foobar();
}
```

You can do the same with `System.Console` like:

```
using System;
using static System.Console;
namespace SomeTestApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Test Message");
            WriteLine("Test Message with Class name");
        }
   }
}
```

EDIT: Since the release of Visual Studio 2015 CTP, in January 2015, static import feature requires explicit mention of `static` keyword like:

```
using static System.Console;
```

Comment: Note that static import does not work for extension methods at least up to .Net 8. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38984853/2987814).

Answer (score 1):

Declare an [Action Delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx) variable in a suitable scope as follows and use it later:

```
Action foobar = () => foo.bar.foobar();
```

or even easier

```
Action foobar = foo.bar.foobar;
```

I shall also pay attention to [Extension Methods (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx). If you're having methods with parameters, often it's quite cosy to have:

```
public static class bar
{
    public static void foobar(this string value)
    {
    }
}
```

and utilize it:

```
 string s = "some value";
 s.foobar();
```

This is actually a much better approach.

Comment: Never knew there was an "Action" keyword. however, this means I have to declare `Action ... ` for every function in a static class I want to use...

Comment: `Action` isn't a keyword, it's a type. This is a clever response, but _please_ don't actually use it.

Comment: @thkang it's not a keyword. It's a delegate See [Action Delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx)

Comment: @PaulPhillips I guess you should explain your comment in greater detail

Comment: @KonstantinVasilcov Where they said "I have to declare Action for every function in a static class" gave me a chill. It's rather demanding to have "no dots" and just hiding what is probably a deeper design problem. I imagined opening a method that used this trick on 5-10 different static functions, and I would not want to inherit that code.

Comment: @PaulPhillips I never said "replace everything". While in some circumstances moderate usage of this may improve readibility of the code.

Comment: @KonstantinVasilcov No, you didn't, but thkang did. That's what I was responding to.

Comment: @PaulPhillips missed that. Definitely agree with you.

Comment: `Action foobar = foo.bar.foobar;` would be slightly lighter weight, not to mention less verbose.

Comment: @phoog Thanks! Edited my answer to reflect your comment

Answer (score 0):

To add to the answers already here it's important to note that C# is a very typed language. Therefore, unless the method exists in the class you're in, you would never be able to do something like what you're looking for.

However, if you add the using:

```
using foo;
```

You can then access it with just the type and method like this:

```
bar.foo();
```