# Code completion support for static imports in NRefactory

Tags: c#, code-completion, nrefactory

Does NRefactory's code completion support static imports? I'm using the latest version of NRefactory and I've not been able to get it to recognize static imports.

e.g:

```
using System.Console;
Console.WriteLine(); //autocomplete for this
WriteLine(); //no autocomplete for this
```

Comment: [You can't import things like this in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14065342/import-a-static-method)

Comment: [Pretty sure you can do that in C# 6.0](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26550114/4328979)

Comment: Are you using it?  If so, it would be useful to include that info in the question.  It's a very new tech, so isn't particularly widely used yet

Comment: Roslyn code completion supports it but I've not been able to get Roslyn to show overloaded method signatures.

Answer (score 1):

No, NRefactory 5.0 does not support features from C# 6. NRefactory 6.0 is only a wrapper around/an extension based on the open-sourced Roslyn library.

[Source: I am part of the NRefactory team.]