# static using doesn't recognize method name, saying the name does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, .net, static, extension-methods, using-directives

**PLEASE NOTE:**  I am aware that [*a similar question*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38984853/2704659) has already [been answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38984941/2704659).  It took me a while to find that question/answer because it assumes I recognized that it *specifically* involves extension methods, which I didn't at first.  I was under the incorrect assumption that the `static using` feature could *only* be used with extension methods, so because of its perceived superfluity I didn't include that when searching.

The purpose of this post is to help people who don't recognize that.

---

I have some code with the `using static directive` that introduced in C# 6:

```
using static MyNs.MyExtensionMethods;
```

I am trying to use an extension method defined in `MyNs.MyExtensionMethods`, and this works (as it always has):

```
foo.MyExtensionMethod();
```

But this does not:

```
MyExtensionMethod(foo);
```

I'm getting a compiler error "The name 'MyExtensionMethod' does not exist in the current context".  What is going on?

Answer (score 1):

As indicated by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38984941/2704659), you cannot use the `using static` directive to allow unqualified access to *extension methods*, only to regular static methods (i.e. without the `this` keyword on the first argument).  The reason is clearly stated in that answer, so I won't duplicate it here.